# Direction when finding bisector length

Tags: analytic-geometry

> Consider the triangle defined by $ A(3, -5)$, $B(1, -3) $ and $ C(2, -2) $.
>   I need to get the length of the angle B external bisector. Here my picture
>   [image]

---

I think I know the process:

- Find the distances
- Get the ratio using the exterior bisector theorem
- Use the ratio formula to get abscissa and ordinate
- And finally get the BD distance

The distances:

$ AB = {\sqrt 8},\quad BC = {\sqrt 2} $

The ratio:

$ \frac{AB}{BC} = \frac{DA}{DC},\quad \frac{\sqrt 8}{\sqrt 2} = \frac{DA}{DC}\quad \frac{DA}{DC} = 2 $

But I'm struggling with the ratio. If I change $ \frac{AB}{BC} = \frac{DA}{DC} $ to $ \frac{AB}{BC} = \frac{AD}{CD} $, I will get the exact same ratio, but different differences in the ratio formula:
$$ r = \frac {x - x_1}{x_2 - x}$$

Ok, that's the expected thing. But the **question** is:

What is the correct order for the bisector theorem when using it with ordered pairs?

Maybe from left to right, or from the bigger side to the short one? I don't know.

---

PD: I would like to stick with this approach since I'm still practicing with the very basics, as you can see :D And the main question is the order for the bisector theorem, not the bisector distance actually.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "angle B exterior bisector". Isn't it a line instead of a segment? How can you talk about its length? Do you have a picture?

Comment: Sorry if my terminology is wrong, the picture is this:

http://imgur.com/CX07hnO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2 = \frac {x-3}{x-2}\\
2x - 4 = x- 3\\
x = 1$

[image]

Comment: Thanks for noticing that! I made a test to check if it always end with the same result no matter the order, the result was it returns the same value only if the order is changed in both the numerator AND the denominator: http://imgur.com/a/KfLmF

Comment: But going back to the question problem, when I use $ \frac {DA}{DC} $ and $ \frac {AD}{CD} $ the result is $ 1 $ but when I use $ \frac {AD}{DC} $ and $ \frac {DA}{CD} $ the result is $ 7/3 $ ... so the question again? which one is the direction should be used?

Comment: I suggest that you do not try to memorize formulas for geometry problems.  Always construct the figure.   Then you can see what the result is that you are looking for.  This is a pretty obscure theorem, and not worth the effort.  You are measuring from $D$ to $C$ and from $D$ to $A.$  The ratio $\frac {AD}{DC}$ would place $D$ between $A$ and $C.$

Comment: I didn't notice about that either! Thanks a lot, I think I should keep practicing, haha, thanks for the suggestion about always construct the figure :-) anything else would you advice regarding this topic?